# Adjust header and footer of ejected page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have an article class document in DIN A4 format.
In an appendix, I have a DIN A3 page ejected in landscape.
I use the `fancyhdr` package to layout the header and footer as follows:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\def\customHeaderChapter{       
    \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[C]{
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(-225,-12){\includegraphics[width=450pt]{bar.png}}
        \end{picture}
    }
    \fancyhead[R]{}
    \fancyfoot[L]{
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(0,-25){\includegraphics[width=60pt]{logo.png}}
        \end{picture}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(-50,-20){\includegraphics[width=150pt]{logo2.png}}
        \end{picture}
    }
    \fancyfoot[R]{}
}

\begin{document}

\customHeaderChapter
\section{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
Plain text.

\newpage
\eject \pdfpagewidth=420mm \pdfpageheight=297mm
\customHeaderChapter
\section{Appendix C}

\newpage
\eject \pdfpagewidth=210mm \pdfpageheight=297mm
\customHeaderChapter
\section{Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
Plain text.


\end{document}
```

How do I manage, that the header and footer on the ejected page are stretched across the entire width and not just maintain DIN A4 width?

Comment: can you please post your code as working example i.e. `\documentclass{article}...
\begin{document}...
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the headers and footers is determined by \headwidth. So you would have to set \headwidth to \pdfpagewidth
So put in the beginning of \customHeaderChapter:

```
\setlength{\headwidth}{\pdfpagewidth}
```

Maybe you also want to make the text wider on that page? In that case look at the changepage package.